# Android - access local host from browser without internet connection

Tags: android

I've installed local web server on my android tablet. But when all connections are off, every time I access the local site from built in browser (or Chrome), I get annoying popup message about "no internet connection" or something about sim card... is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: If you are sure there are no external references in the site, it may be some undesired online database behavior of chrome - are you "logged in to chrome"?  Have you tried another browser?  At an extreme, you could make your own viewer which just uses a webview on the content - at a minimum this would verify that the site can display independent of connection, and not giving its package Internet permission would be an interesting check!   In your current case, does the site actually display after the warning?

Comment: Site displays, no external files loaded, it is not only in Chrome. In default browser too. System is totally clean, browser was never used before after hard reset. Tested on few tablets. Galaxy Tab 2 says something about sim card. To check if sim card is present. But still it is all about no internet connection. Message appears every time site changes. So when clickin on some link on the local site, that takes to other local page, message appears again. Really annoying.

Comment: Did you try with third-party browsers (e.g., Firefox)?

Comment: I did try other browsers, most of them don't even know what to do with localhost. Few of them totally aren't working offline, because they proxify all connections. FireFox crashes too much, and doesn't correctly display the site I need to use, so I didn't try it. I thought it would be as easy as changeing something in config files, but I guess it is not.

Comment: Can you give me the exact error you get, and also the web server that you are using?

Comment: No error. Local BitWeb Server.

Comment: I mean what happens when you enter localhost in your browser?

Comment: Have you tried `127.0.0.1` as address instead of `localhost`?

Comment: What model tablet is it?

Comment: Sorry, I tried now, still the same. Thought it didn't work because I forgot about port. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

Comment: Please check my edited answer and see if that helps with your problem.

Comment: in my case, the only 2 things that helped so far was using Firefox or going to `chrome://offline-internals` and clearing out the localhost. yes, I have tried 127, same thing. as long as you never enter a the link with internet on, there's no cache created. so... still hoping for a better solution! 

Comment: nevermind. i now have to manually delete it there every time! dreadful...

Answer (score 3):

Most Browsers will check for an Internet connection when they start. What you can do (depending on how you are planning to use it):

- Use WebView or [Chromium Webview](https://github.com/mogoweb/chromium_webview) to create your own "browser"
- Modify an existing browser: [android default browser](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser) or [lightning](https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser)

If you choose for an existing browser to modify, I would recommend lightning because (as a quick look at the strings.xml file would suggest) It does not check for an internet connection.

Comment: Lightning can't read local host (neither ip). It always tries to search. The problem is much complicated than no internet message at start. It shows it on every page change. Using webview may be solution, but it is not an answer to my question. I could write my own OS as well :-)

Comment: I understand, but because I'm from opinion that there is no way to disable chrome's internet check (besides faking a internet connection or something), I came with the (in my opinion) best alternative.

Comment: Are you sure WebView won't show those kind of messages?

Comment: What WebView will do is show an error message in case it can't establish an connection. WebView does not require an internet connection (http://coderzen.blogspot.nl/2013/11/using-android-simulator-webview-with.html)

Comment: `+1` but I can't accept it. Too many people are waiting for problem with native browser to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

> Problem may be caused by HTTP Proxy server. Proxies help to manage web
>   traffic on the providers end, but can and probably will disrupt access
>   to local addresses. Proxy options may be available in your network
>   settings, but on many phones these options are hidden. An app such as
>   HTTP Proxy Settings will give access to the hidden settings. Simply
>   clear out the hostname and port for un-proxied access. Make sure to
>   write down original values so changes can be undone.
>
> If your device is configured to use a web proxy, then it'll never
>   connect directly to localhost: it connects to the web proxy and asks
>   that for the web page you really want. This won't work with a local
>   web server.
>
> To use a local web server, turn off your web proxy settings.

[Original Answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59225/why-can-i-not-access-my-devices-localhost-over-data)
[Original Answer #2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28726/cant-access-tethered-server-from-android-browser-time-out-or-url-blocked)

Comment: No proxy settings. Tab was freshly formatted. I noticed that Chrome Beta is not displaying this message. But it crashes too much.

Answer (score 2):

Four years later, I find myself googling for an answer to the same issue, and found this discussion. Just in case someone else is in the same boat...

Firefox Focus does work with a local server on 127.0.0.1 with WiFi off. At least, does on a tablet in perpetual "airplane mode" with no phone provider hidden proxy issues. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

*as a complement to the @hermann answer* ,the localhost address in android devices is `10.0.0.2` (it is the equivalent of `127.0.0.1` address ). 
So try using 10.0.0.2 and share your result with us :)